# How do you calculate the theoretical work function of an alloy?

Tags: electrons, photoelectric-effect, metals

Given a combination of metals or metals combined with one or more other elements, how do you calculate the theoretical work function of the alloy?

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is a very difficult problem.

Unlike some physical properties (elastic modulus, for example), most electrical properties have a very complex relationship with the underlying composition and structure of the material. Work function is especially tricky, as it is also influenced by the properties of the material's surface.

In theory, one find a work function analytically by solving Schrodinger's equation, and calculating the energy in the lattice compared to the energy in a vacuum just outside the lattice. There are some models which do this semi-accurately (e.g. the uniform electron gas model), but you'll need to know at least the crystal structure of your material.